# Passing an array of structs "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type"?

Tags: c++

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestStuff.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
int StuScore;
string StuName;
};

int main() {
int choice;
cout << "What's the size of your dynamic array? ";
cin >> choice;
cout << endl;
int SIZE = 10;
Student *testScore = nullptr;
testScore = new Student[10];

TestStuff ts;
ts.EnterScores(testScore, SIZE);
ts.QuickSortScores(testScore, SIZE);
ts.AvgScore(testScore, SIZE);
ts.DisplayScore(testScore, SIZE);

delete[] testScore;
testScore = nullptr;
system("Pause");
return 0;
};
```

TestStuff.h

```
#pragma once
class TestStuff {
private:
    double avg;
public:
    void EnterScores(struct Student *, int);

    void QuickSortScores(struct Student *, int &);
    void QuickSortScores(struct Student *, int, int);
    int QuickSortParti(struct Student *, int, int);
    void QuickSortSwap(struct Student *, struct Student *);

    void AvgScore(struct Student *, int);
    void DisplayScore(struct Student *, int);
};
```

TestStuff.cpp

```
#include <iostream>;
#include "TestStuff.h";
#include <string>;
using namespace std;

void TestStuff::EnterScores(Student *TestScore, int SIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << endl << "Enter Name of Student " << i + 1;
        cin >> (*(TestScore + i)).StuName; //error here
        cout << "Enter sutdent " << i + 1 << " Test score integer: ";
        cin >> (*(TestScore + i)).StuScore; //error here
    }
}

void TestStuff::QuickSortScores(Student *SortScores, int &SIZE)
{
    int high = SIZE - 1;
    int low = 0;
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = QuickSortParti(SortScores, low, high);

        QuickSortScores(SortScores, low, pi - 1); // Recursion ;)
        QuickSortScores(SortScores, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

void TestStuff::QuickSortScores(Student *SortScores, int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = QuickSortParti(SortScores, low, high);
        QuickSortScores(SortScores, low, pi - 1);
        QuickSortScores(SortScores, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

int TestStuff::QuickSortParti(Student *SortScores, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = (*(SortScores + high)).StuScore;
    int i = (low - 1);
    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
    {
        if ((*(SortScores + j)).StuScore <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
            QuickSortSwap((SortScores + i), (SortScores + j));
        }
    }
    QuickSortSwap((SortScores + (i + 1)), (SortScores + high));
    return (i + 1);
}

void TestStuff::QuickSortSwap(Student *a, Student *b)
{
    string n = (*a).StuName;
    int s = (*a).StuScore;
    (*a).StuName = (*b).StuName;
    (*a).StuScore = (*b).StuScore;
    (*b).StuName = n;
    (*b).StuScore = s;
}

void TestStuff::AvgScore(Student *TestScore, int SIZE)
{
    double total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < SIZE; i++) {
        total += (*(TestScore + i)).StuScore;
    }
    total = total / i;
    avg = total;
}

void TestStuff::DisplayScore(Student *TestScore, int SIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << (*(TestScore + i)).StuName << "'s test score: ";
        cout << (*(TestScore + i)).StuScore << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Average test score: " << avg << endl;
}
```

I get this error throughout my code in TestStuff.cpp wherever I try to input data of each student to the attributes of the struct Student. Additionally, wherever I call the variable, of the pointer, to an array of structs it gives me either this error or "incomplete type is not allowed" or "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type". I'm constrained to using pointer notation.

Comment: How could the header file `TestStuff.h` or the source file `TestStuff.cpp` know about the structure `Student` if it's defined in the `Main.cpp` source file *only*?

Comment: Also, unless its part of the exercise, don't use dynamic allocations for your "array". Either use a static fixed-size array (e.g. `Student testScore[10];`) or use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (e.g. `std::array<Student, 10> testScore;`) or use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (e.g. `std::vector<Student> testScore(10);`)

Comment: Do you know how I could make Student defined in both? I'm only in an introductory course. I'm really new at this, and dynamic array allocation is apart of the exercise.

Comment: Put the structure in the header file instead?

Comment: I really wanted to, but I should've made clear that I have to pass the structure, and I can only use pointers to modify the original array that I'm passing.

Comment: Still possible with all three other methods. :)  For all three you could pass a pointer to the first element, i.e. `&testScore[0]`. And with a plain array then you could just use the variable name `testScore` as that will *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot.